# How to Limit the paginate in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-1.2

How to Limit the paginate in cakephp ?

Assume that i have 400 records.
I need to get only 25 records from 50th record to 75th record
and need to display 5 records per page.
How i can do this in paginate ?

Sample Code:

```
        $this->paginate = array(
                'contain'=>array('User'),
                'recursive' => 2,
                'order' => array('Profile.winning' => 'DESC'),
                'limit' =>5

            );
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can set conditions for the pagination.

```
function listRecords()
  {
  $this->paginate = array(
    'conditions' => array('Model.id >=' => 50, 'Model.id <=' => 75),
    'limit' => 5
    );
  $this->paginate('Model');
  );
```

### EDIT:

A solution from [here](http://ask.cakephp.org/questions/view/limit_total_number_of_results_in_pagination):

```
$this->paginate = array(
  'limit' => 20,
  'totallimit' => 1000
  );
```

And then in the Model:

```
public function paginateCount($conditions = null, $recursive = 0, $extra = array())
  {
  if( isset($extra['totallimit']) ) return $extra['totallimit'];
  }
```

Comment: I am using order by so i cant give 'Model.id' in conditions... my result need to display only last 25 records according to high 'Profile.winning'

Comment: Oh, that's a completely different story. Not so easy to do that in Cake as it turns out.

Comment: Edited the answer. Not liking it too much though. It just seems strange that Cake doesn't have a built-in, core solution for that...

Comment: 2nd solution works! Just bit inconvenience need to edit both model & controller

Comment: also unfortunately it must return a totallimit value; and if the records is less than totallimit, the paging still stick to totallimit value

Answer (score 2):

Improved version with reference of: http://www.mainelydesign.com/blog/view/best-paginatecount-cakephp-with-group-by-support

This return the correct total count base on whichever is less.

```
public function paginateCount($conditions = null, $recursive = 0, $extra = array()) 
    {
        $conditions = compact('conditions');
        if ($recursive != $this->recursive) {
            $conditions['recursive'] = $recursive;
        }
        unset( $extra['contain'] );
        $count = $this->find('count', array_merge($conditions, $extra));

        if (isset($extra['group'])) {
            $count = $this->getAffectedRows();
        }

        if (isset($extra['totallimit']) && $extra['totallimit'] < $count) {
            return $extra['totallimit'];
        }

        return $count;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `maxLimit` in CakePHP v2.x .

```
public $paginate = array(
    // other keys here.
    'maxLimit' => 10
);
```

read more about it [here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/pagination.html#limit-the-maximum-number-of-rows-that-can-be-fetched).

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = $this->User->find('all', [
    'recursive' => 2,
    'order' => array('Profile.winning' => 'DESC'),
    'limit' => 25, 
    'offset' => 50
]);
$this->paginate = array(
    $query,
    'limit' => 5
);
```

Comment: Please add an explanation that explains what this code does to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In cakephp 4.x version we have to call like below

```
 public function index()
    {
        $this->loadComponent('Paginator');
        $settings = array(
            'limit' => 50
        );
        $prices = $this->Paginator->paginate($this->Prices->find(), $settings);
        $this->set(compact('prices'));
    }
```